# How to solve a query that has group by, joins, and Boolean groupation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables in my university project

1. table offer:

   id, patid, description, preferred_language,created
2. table offer_country:

   id, offer_id, patid, country
3. table response_clinic_reserved:

   id, offer_id, patid, clinid, country, created, expire
4. table response_clinic_final:

   id, offer_id, patid, clinid, country, price_low, price_high, offer_description

For example a company with id 6 from us makes a request to list all offers

I would need to list all offers for the US, and to show how many final offers and reservations there are. But if that combination **us/6** has already made reservation (**response_clinic_reserved**) or already made final response (**response_clinic_final**) then do not show that offer

This is my query that does not work as it should

```
SELECT offer.id, offer.description, offer.preferred_language, offer.created, count(rcr.id) as reservations, count(rcf.id) as offers 
FROM offer 
LEFT JOIN offer_country ON offer_country.offer_id = offer.id 
LEFT JOIN response_clinic_reserved rcr ON rcr.offer_id = offer.id 
LEFT JOIN response_clinic_final rcf ON rcf.offer_id = offer.id 
WHERE (offer_country.country = 'ALL' OR offer_country.country = 'us') 
  AND (rcf.country <> 'us' AND rcf.clinid <> 6) 
GROUP BY offer.id 
ORDER BY offer.created ASC 
LIMIT 50
```

UPDATE: 2019-06-03 at 10:10

I have created new query that is behaving as it should (i think it is), but it might be to complex. Is there a way to make it faster ? I also hope that there is no hidden error.

```
SELECT offer.id, offer.description, offer.preferred_language, 
             if( 
                rcf.clinid IS NOT NULL,
                max( rcf.clinid = 6 AND rcf.country = 'us'),
                0
             ) as offer_response_present,
             if( 
                rcr.clinid IS NOT NULL,
                max( rcr.clinid = 6 AND rcr.country = 'us'),
                0
             ) as offer_reservation_present,
             offer.created, count(rcr.id) as reservations, count(rcf.id) as offers 
             FROM offer 
             LEFT JOIN offer_country 
             ON offer_country.offer_id = offer.id 
             LEFT JOIN response_clinic_reserved rcr 
             ON rcr.offer_id = offer.id 
             LEFT JOIN response_clinic_final rcf 
             ON rcf.offer_id = offer.id 
             WHERE (offer_country.country = 'ALL' OR offer_country.country = 'us') 
             GROUP BY offer.id 
             HAVING  ( offer_response_present NOT LIKE 1 AND offer_reservation_present NOT LIKE 1)
             ORDER BY offer.created ASC 
             LIMIT 50
```

The reason for if in query is in cases where table (response_clinic_final or response_clinic_reserved) is empty or have no results, then

```
HAVING  ( offer_response_present NOT LIKE 1 AND offer_reservation_present NOT LIKE 1)
```

will not work. so in cases where there is no results i return 0

UPDATE 2019-07-03 10:40

Last query did not work well,

```
count(rcr.id) as reservations, count(rcf.id) as offers
```

This part of the query returned more results then it should, as a result of left joins, so i had to fix that part by making sub selections like in the following query.

```
SELECT offer.id, offer.description, offer.preferred_language, 
             if( 
                rcf.clinid IS NOT NULL,
                max( rcf.clinid = 4 AND rcf.country = 'us'),
                0
             ) as offer_response_present,
             if( 
                rcr.clinid IS NOT NULL,
                max( rcr.clinid = 4 AND rcr.country = 'us'),
                0
             ) as offer_reservation_present,
             offer.created, 
             (SELECT Count(offer_id) FROM response_clinic_reserved WHERE offer_id = offer.id) as reservations, 
             (SELECT Count(offer_id) FROM response_clinic_final WHERE offer_id = offer.id) as offers 
             FROM offer 
             LEFT JOIN offer_country 
             ON offer_country.offer_id = offer.id 
             LEFT JOIN response_clinic_reserved rcr  ON rcr.offer_id = offer.id 
             LEFT JOIN response_clinic_final rcf 
             ON rcf.offer_id = offer.id 
             WHERE (offer_country.country = 'ALL' OR offer_country.country = 'us') 
             GROUP BY offer.id 
             HAVING  ( offer_response_present NOT LIKE 1 AND offer_reservation_present NOT LIKE 1)
             ORDER BY offer.created ASC 
             LIMIT 50
```

Now there are more selections then i would like to have, is there a way to optimize this query ?

edit 2019-10-03 at 10:15

This is the last version that went in to production. Do not know if it is the fastest but it is the cleanest.

```
SELECT offer.id, offer.description, offer.preferred_language, offer.created, 
            (   
                SELECT Count(offer_id) 
                FROM response_clinic_reserved 
                WHERE offer_id = offer.id
                AND country = :clin_country
                AND clinid = :clinid
            ) as offer_response_present,
            
            (   
                SELECT Count(offer_id) 
                FROM response_clinic_final 
                WHERE offer_id = offer.id
                AND country = :clin_country
                AND clinid = :clinid
            ) as offer_reservation_present,
            
            (   
                SELECT Count(offer_id) 
                FROM response_clinic_reserved 
                WHERE offer_id = offer.id
                AND country = :clin_country
            ) as reservations, 
             
            (
                SELECT Count(offer_id) 
                FROM response_clinic_final 
                WHERE offer_id = offer.id
                AND country = :clin_country
            ) as offers

            FROM offer 
            
            LEFT JOIN offer_country 
            
            ON offer_country.offer_id = offer.id 
            
            WHERE (offer_country.country = 'ALL' OR offer_country.country = :clin_country) 
            
            GROUP BY offer.id 
            
            ORDER BY offer.created ASC 
            
            LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Based on you using `LIMIT` it looks like you use MySQL.  Add it or any other appropriate DBMS-specific tag to your question.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Start by using proper `GROUP BY`.  All non-aggregated columns must in in `GROUP BY`.